# Too many Rewrite Rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I had to redesign a site last week. The problem is that last urls weren't seo friendly so, in order to avoid Google penalizing my site because too many 404 errors, I have to create a lot of Rewrite Rules because all the content had awful URL's ( and that content had a good position on SERP's).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^documents/documents_for_subject/22-ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas http://%{HTTP_HOST}/1o-bachillerato/matematicas-cc.ss/aritmetica-y-algebra/ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas [R=301,L]
```

Is this a problem on my performance? Is there another solution to my situation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to force a *header* redirect instead of an internal one? Are the contents not on the same domain?

Comment: yes. They are in the same domain. Are you suggesting an internal redirect is better? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They are in the same domain.

Then an internal redirect is much better. A header redirect sends the new URL to the browser and causes it to make a new request; an internal one is handled, as the name says, internally.

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^documents/documents_for_subject/22-ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas /1o-bachillerato/matematicas-cc.ss/aritmetica-y-algebra/ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas [L]
```

Any performance issues are going to be negligible with this - except maybe if you have many thousands or tens of thousands of individual rules, those may slow down Apache. In that case, if you have access to the central server configuration, put the rules there instead of a .htaccess file, because instructions in the server config get stored in memory and are faster.

Comment: Internal redirect is not the best way as it will provide content on old urls which crawlers will treat as duplicate one, as it is served from urls in new scheme as well. So 301 redirect is better by giving clear signal that the new location is where content will stay in the future. Still, if there are many external links pointing to the old addresses and additional delay caused by redirect is an issue, then internal redirect may be an acceptable solution, but then it would be good to add `<link rel canonical="..." /> to help disambiguate which url is the proper one to get page rank "juice".

Answer (score 1):

A. Yes using 301 is the right way to notify search bots about changed URLs and eventually your old URL's will be removed from search results.

B. You don't need to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` in your rewrite rule just use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^documents/documents_for_subject/22-ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas http://%{HTTP_HOST}/1o-bachillerato/matematicas-cc.ss/aritmetica-y-algebra/ecuaciones-exponenciales-y-logaritmicas [R=301,L]
```

C. If you have lots of RewriteRules like above I recommend using [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) or else use some scripting support (like PHP) to redirect from old to new URL with 301.